# How to attaching automation test results to ms teams channel?

Tags: playwright, npm-package, test-results

I am currently running my automation (UI) tests on azure devops release pipeline using Playwright. Whenever the test run finishes I Need a notification to my teams using bot. but i face some issue like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiMl3.png) i am using playwright test runner

Now my question is: is it possible to use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-results-reporter NPM Package for playwright testing fream work

Comment: might be possible, since Playwright output the test result as JUnit format